# In a java project,for all the constituent package ,is it mandatory to have only one main function?

Tags: java

Inside a java project ,for subsequent packages, does creating separate main () function for each package is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. To start a Java program, you have to specify a class to run. This class must (in general) have a `public static void main(String... args)` method. Java does not "know" projects, only packages, classes, interfaces and enums. If you, however, have multiple `main(String... args)` methods within a project in your IDE (e.g. Eclipse), you must take care of your launch configurations to ensure you start the correct `main(String... args)`. You may want to look up how to configure the run configurations of your IDE.